# Grails 2.2.3 + Spring security core + Multi-tenant Single DB plugin

Tags: multi-tenant

I am new to grails and I am trying to implement spring security core and Multi-tenant single db plugin.
I have implemented the spring security core first and implemented custom AuthenticationProvider and Authentication.
Then I have installed the multi-tenant single db plugin and ran the 'mt-spring-security' script that automatically created custom tenantResolver and tenantRepository. I have hard-coded the tenantId in tenantResolver for testing purpose.
I have added the @MultiTenant annotation in the domain classes.

@MultiTenant

class ClientUser implements Serializable {

```
long idclient_user
Userprofile user
Client client
int tenantId
...
```

}

In the AuthenticationProvider, the ClientUser data is not filtered for the current tenant. It is bringing the data the all the tenant.

class ClientAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

```
Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
    ClientAuthentication authentication = auth
    String password = authentication.credentials
    String username = authentication.name
    String clientName = authentication.clientName
    ...
    Userprofile.withTransaction { status ->

        def user = Userprofile.findWhere(username: username)
        def client = Client.findWhere(clientname: clientName)
        def clientUser = ClientUser.findWhere(client: client, user: user) <-- NOT FILTERED FOR THE CURRENT TENANT. I HARD-CODED INVALID TENANTID IN THE TENANTRESOLVER AND EXPECTING IT TO FAIL BUT IT STILL FINDS THE USER.

        if (!clientUser) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException('User not found', username)
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
    result
}
```

I am not sure how the multi-tenant and spring security works together. I am having a hard time understanding the Architecture/design.

If anyone could provided me with a sample implementation or point me in the right direction, it will be really helpful.
Thanks,
dinesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the multitenant filter was registered before the spring security filter so the tenantResolver was not called until after the Spring security authentication. I fixed this problem by setting the resolveTenantBeforeLogin to true in the config.groovy

In config.groovy, add this line

multiTenant.resolveTenantBeforeLogin=true

After i added this line, the tenantResolver is called first and then the authentication.